# How to disconnect from network via wpa_cli?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli, wpa-cli

Is there a way to disconnect from a network via `wpa_cli`?  I'm reading the man page and I've been able to use `wpa_cli` to connect to my router via push-button connect (WPS); however I'm trying to write a script that will disconnect from the network upon a certain event.

I attempted to find the network via `nmcli` but the network I'm connected to doesn't even show up when invoking the `nmcli connection show -active` command.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just do `wpa_cli disconnect` to disconnect, and `wpa_cli reconnect` to connect again.

Alternatively, you can also `ifdown`/`ifup` your wlan interface.

BTW, the man page of `wpa_cli` for some reason only lists a few commands; use `wpa_cli help` for a much longer list.

(I can't help you with the `nmcli` issue).

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect from the network via [`wpa_cli`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README) you can use the following commands:

```
disable_network <network id>
```

> It is used to  disable the network

```
disconnect
```

> disconnect and wait for reassociate command before connecting

```
 terminate
```

> terminate `wpa_supplicant`

**edit**

> the network I'm connected to doesn't even show up when invoking the `nmcli connection show -active`

You should save your configuration through `save_config` command.

Comment: "disable network" only excludes one particular network (i.e. BSSID) from the list of networks to automatically connect to. While this would also work, it's probably not what is wanted.